# Does the uniqueness of the supremum refer to an element in the set or its `position'?

Tags: order-theory

I'm confused on how a supremum or infinum is necessarily unique, if they exist. I have a function $f(x)=x^2$, and I want to define a weak partial order on the set $\mathbb{R}$, by
$$
\text{$x\succ y$  if  $f(x)\geq f(y)$,}
$$
and I want to say this is also a totally ordered set, if that's relevant. Consider a subset $S=[0,5]\subset\mathbb{R}$. I think I would be correct to say that the infinum of $S$ is $0$, and that the supremum is $5$.

But if I have a subset $S'=[-5,5]$, then what would the supremum be?

I would say that $-5$ or $5$ are candidates for the supremum, but I heard that the supremum is unique, and I would also say that $-5\neq5$. Does this mean that this set doesn't have a supremum?

Does $S'$ have a supremum? More generally, does the uniqueness of the supremum refer to the uniqueness of the element in the ordered set (or parent set), or the `relative position' that element holds? This [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99812/how-many-supremums-and-infimums-can-a-set-have/99821#99821) I've seen implies that it's the former.

Comment: You may want to use a different type of inequality such as $\prec$, since it seems you are defining a nonstandard inequality $<$ for the reals in terms of the standard inequality $<$ for the reals (using the same symbol $<$).  So I find your definitions to be confusing.

Comment: Thank you; I've just edited my question to make the distinction clearer!

Comment: But in any case, a "supremum" is generally a "least upper bound" for a set or sequence, and so it does not matter if that value occurs in the set/sequence of interest or not (or how many times that value occurs).  I do not think the concept of supremum and infimum will be useful in your problem because a general ordering does not need to assign a "value" to the elements that are ordered.

Comment: If it helps, I observe that both $1\prec -1$ and $-1 \prec 1$ fail.

Comment: That's true, so I've changed it to a weak partial order to make it a total order.

Comment: So now $1\prec -1$ and $-1 \prec 1$ are both true.

Comment: That's my intention, so does that mean that this is not an example of a poset?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146158/discussion-between-samuel-han-and-michael).

Answer (score 1):

Uniqueness of suprema (if they exist) follows from anti-symmetry of the order relation. Typically, we discuss orderings only in an anri-symmetric setting. By working with a weak partial order instead, you lose uniqueness of suprema.